# Determine iOS Simulator selected device

Tags: ios

Is there a way to programmatically determine which simulated device is being used in the iPhone sim? UIDevice just returns iPhone Simulator, whether I pick iPhone4, 5s, 6, iPad, etc.

Comment: Why do you need to know? What is your goal?

Answer (score 1):

For know the current device.

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] >= 2.0)

#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
```

Comment: Do not use these. Anyone using these macros is doing it all wrong.

Comment: Please see the [Adaptivity and Size Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheAdaptiveModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH19-SW1) section of the View Controller Programming Guide for iOS.

Comment: They asked for a way to determine which *simulator* is running. A valid need in that not all of us own every device for testing and yet want to validate that every kind of device is handled correctly. My need for this info is to patch some code that predates Autolayout and the Size Classes. I "should" rewrite that code, but I don't have a budget for rewriting tons of code, so I need to patch around it. This is the only inexpensive way to do it. Doing the work within budget always trumps the theory when the choice is between not fixing a bug and doing it the "wrong" way.

Comment: For new code, avoid using this approach, rmaddy's link to the docs above is a much better solution. I have to maintain some old iOS 4 code and it is a major pain, the new approach is so much better and avoids having to patch size problems as new devices and capabilities like multitasking appear.